# Moving Objects Relatively With Their Parent Object [Gamemaker]

Tags: game-maker

I have an object type, `oFur`, instances of which are generated in a random distribution over the sprite area of a parent object, `oFurArea`.

However, I would like the `oFurArea` to change its `image_xscale` and `image_yscale` dynamically, as well as its `y` position. This is easy to do, but I would also like all of the `oFur` instances to move with their parent (i.e. change their own 'y' values), whilst maintaining their relative positions on the parent object.

Either I'm having a brain-fart, or I cannot work out how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You mean you want to move `oFurArea` by `foo` and then move every `oFur` by `foo` too?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `foo`? The `oFurArea` changes its `y` every step at a `ChangeRate` variable. I would like the `oFur` to change its `y` position at this same rate _whilst_ maintaining its position relative to the `oFurArea`. I realise that I could just duplicate the y-changing code in the Step Event of the `oFur`, but a more elegant solution would be to update the `oFur`'s 'y' variable every step based on `oFurArea`'s `y`.

Comment: Ah, I see now what you mean by `foo`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar

Comment: You can try this, maybe it will work: in the create event save in a variable the difference between `oFur.y` and `oFurArea.y`. Then on step, make `oFur.y = oFurArea.y + difference;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DH above, I've managed to find an elegant solution to this, I think.

Every step, the `oFurArea` updates its `Difference` variable as the *distance between its original y value and its current y value*. This needs to be done every step, as `oFurArea` is constantly moving:

```
Difference = OriginalY - y
```

Each `oFur` instance than also has an `OriginalY` value, set upon Create. Every step, they set their own `y` value to a distance *relative to `oFurArea`'s distance*.

Therefore, if the distance between oFurArea's current `y` and its `OriginalY` was 15 pixels, each `oFur`'s `y` would be 15 pixels from its own `OriginalY` as well. This keeps everything relative to each other.

So, in the `oFur`'s Step event:

```
y = OriginalY - oFurArea.Difference
```

I think this solution is elegant as it only requires two variables and only two lines of code. Thank you for the help, DH.